# How to make MainActivity ready before SplashActivity finish?

Tags: android, android-intent, splash-screen, activity-finish

I'd like to make my splash screen more smooth. I maked splash screen after I read this [link](https://android.jlelse.eu/the-complete-android-splash-screen-guide-c7db82bce565). However, when I finish SplashActivity and intent to MainActivity, I feel SplashActivity finish too early, I saw screen saver of my device before MainActivity show (I estimate the delay to be 0.5s). What I want is the MainActivity ready before the SplashActivity finish.

I tried the solutio that is set flags FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK in my Intent, but it's not make smooth.

Below is the code for transtion between 2 activities:

```
private void transitionActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

And Manifest file:

```
<activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/SplashScreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar" />
```

Comment: what do you mean by making MainActivity ready?

Comment: If you load information in your main activity, it must be loaded in the splash, and after you get it, the main activity can load that information. or, if you want you can use a loading dialog to load asynk the data.

Comment: @KiranMalvi I want the content view of MainActivity ready; because I want when I finish SplashActivity, I will see MainActivity instead of the screen saver of my device (maybe it cause of finish too early). Content view of MainActivity is a login form.

Comment: @GilbertoIbarra MainActivity is a login form, so I do not load any thing, I just want when I finish SplashActivity, I will see MainActivity instead of the screen saver of device. I know the reason I see the screen saver, it is because of finish SplashActivity too early.

Comment: if you dont load nothing, the problem could be other, maybe you have a big bitmap  in your xml, in other hand, maybe you only have a slow phone, idk.

Comment: @GilbertoIbarra My background I set is a drawable xm file, only a gradient background. And I test in Galaxy On5 2016, so I think my phone is good enough =)))

Comment: first start your Main activity and then finish splash activity, and also check for stack trace to see if there is a problem loading big bitmap.

Comment: Android have it'z life cycle must you have to follow. you have to set decrease splash screen time 3000 ms. and redirect Main Activity. If you have big bitmap or in your design you have use linear layout and linear layout have number of weight property assign to it'z view it will load slow. check your bitmap and use less weight property if you use linear layout.

Comment: @ShockWave so, how can I finish SplashActivity when I'm stay in MainActivity, have you any idea?

Comment: if really you dont want that, delete the splashActivity, and make a dialogFragment over the activity , you could have two fragments, with fragment add, both fragments will be created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe the point is he want to give delay in splash screen

if that so you can do that using Handler()

```
int SplashDuration = 2000;
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent i = new Intent(splashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }

            }, SplashDuration);
```

and if that still to fast or to slow for you, you can change the time at "SplashDuration"

Comment: Your solution doesn't solve my problem, but it helps me think of a way to solve my problem. The 'run' function in Runnable, I keep the 'finish ()' and I bring the rest out of Runnable. The type is: startActivity (intent); new Handler (). postDelayed (...); So, now, can you update your answer so I can vote for you?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I want to thank everyone who has answered me as well as commented on my question. There is one answer of @MOF ([answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54897714/how-to-make-mainactivity-ready-before-splashactivity-finish/54899691#54899691)), it does not solve the problem, but it helps me think of a new way, and this new way helps my problem no longer exist. My way is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                finish();
            }
        }, getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_mediumAnimTime));
```

Thank all of you!

Answer (score 0):

you can using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html for do it.
make logic when splashscreen until 5 seconds, make when 4 seconds or below to call your main activity.

Comment: You mean I should have an AsyncTask in SplashActivity, and it run until 5 seconds. After 4 seconds, I run code startActivity(intent)?

Comment: I tried, and no any changes. However, I'd like to say thanks with you, thanks for your answer.